# how to load the same html several times with different values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script, bootstrap-4

In a webapp developed with google script, I want to display a list of ideas with title, description, initiator, status etc. The information is stored in an array of objects called "ideas"

In the Index file I have a table.

```
<table>
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="listOfIdeas">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the javascript file, I loop through "ideas", and each time I append a string, in which I insert the various information from the array that I want to display

```
for (var i=0;i<ideas.length;i++){
$('#listOfIdeas')
  .append('<tr class="border-bottom shadow-down">'+
          '<td class="idea d-none">'+ideas[i].ideaNumber+'</td>'+
          '<td class="p-1">'+
              '<div class="main-cell p-1">'+
                  '<div><strong>'+ideas[i].title+'</strong>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<div class="desc" style="word-break:break-word;">'+ideas[i].description+
                  '</div><br>'+
                  '<div class="creatorInfo"><i><span class="founder">'+ideas[i].initiator+'</span>, '+
                          '<span>'+ideas[i].department+'</span>, '+
                          '<span class="heart far fa-thumbs-up"></span>'+
                          '<span class="score">'+ideas[i].count+'</span></i>, '+
                          '<span class="msg far fa-envelope"></span>'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<div class="tags">'+
                  '</div>'+
                  '<div class="application">'+
                      '<span class="badge badge-info status"></span>'+
                      '<button class="float-right app-part d-none">Participate</button>'+
                  '</div>'+
              '</div>'+                          
          '</td>'+
          '</tr>')
```

My problem is, as I would like to add new functionalities (with a small menu with buttons), the string will become less and less readable.

Is there a "cleaner" way to proceed? I feel like it would be possible to add the template in the index file, and copy it several times with different values, but i'm not clear on whether it's the best solution.

Comment: For better readability, consider using a template literal with interpolated values, and extracting the values of the object beforehand (hopefully with `forEach` rather than a  `for` loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use es6 template literals, using backticks

```
for (var i = 0; i < ideas.length; i++){
$(#listOfIdeas)
  .append(`<tr class="border-bottom shadow-down">
          <td class="idea d-none">${ideas[i].ideaNumber}</td>
          <td class="p-1">
              <div class="main-cell p-1">
                  <div><strong>${ideas[i].title}</strong>
                  </div>
                  <div class="desc" style="word-break:break-word;">${ideas[i].description}
                  </div><br>
                  <div class="creatorInfo"><i><span class="founder">${ideas[i].initiator}</span>, 
                          <span>${ideas[i].department}</span>, 
                          <span class="far fa-thumbs-up"></span>
                          <span class="score">${ideas[i].count}</span></i>, 
                          <span class="msg far fa-envelope"></span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="tags">
                  </div>
                  <div class="application">
                      <span class="badge badge-info status"></span>
                      <button class="float-right app-part d-none">Participate</button>
                  </div>
              </div>                          
          </td>
          </tr>`)
}
```